# When working with NodeJS FS mkdir, what is the importance of including callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, filesystems

I'm playing with the `NodeJS REPL` console and following this tutorial.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_file_system.htm

I'm focusing on the `File System(FS)` module. Let's look at the `mkdir` function used for creating directories.

According to TutorialsPoint, this  is how you create a directory with FS

```
var fs = require("fs");

console.log("Going to create directory /tmp/test");
fs.mkdir('/tmp/test',function(err){
   if (err) {
       return console.error(err);
   }
   console.log("Directory created successfully!");
});
```

They specifically say you need this syntax

```
fs.mkdir(path[, mode], callback)
```

Well I just tried using less code without the callback and it worked.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.mkdir('new-directory');
```

And the directory was created. The syntax should just be

```
fs.mkdir(path);
```

I have to ask, what is the purpose of the callback and do you really need it? For removing a directory I could understand why you would need it, in case the directory didn't exist. But I can't see what could possibly go wrong with the `mkdir` command. Seems like a lot of unnecessary code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of node v10.0, the callback to `fs.mkdir()` is required.  You must pass it, even if you just pass a dummy function that does nothing.

The point of the callback is to let you know if and when the call succeeded and if it didn't succeed, what the specific error was.

Remember, this type of function is asynchronous.  It completes some unknown time in the future so the only way to know when it is done or if it completed successfully is by passing a callback function and when the callback is called, you can check the error and see that it has completed.

As it turns out, there are certainly things that can go wrong with `mkdir()` such as a bad path, a permissions error, etc... so errors can certainly happen.  And, if you want to immediately use that new directory, you have to wait until the callback is called before using it.

In response to one of your other comments, the `fs.mkdir()` function is always asynchronous whether you pass the callback or not.

Here's an example:

```
var path = '/tmp/test';
fs.mkdir(path, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('failed to create directory', err);
    } else {
        fs.writeFile(path + "/mytemp", myData, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error writing file', err);
            } else {
                console.log('writing file succeeded');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

---

**Note:** Modern versions of nodejs, include [`fs.promises.mkdir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_mkdir_path_options) which returns a promise that resolves/rejects instead of using plain callbacks.  This allows you to use `await` with `try/catch` or `.then()` and `.catch()` instead of the plain callback to know when it's done and promises make it typically easier to sequence in with other asynchronous operations and to centralize error handling.

Comment: Edited to note that as of node v10.0, the callback to `fs.mkdir()` is required (not optional) and `fs.promises.mkdir()` is available which returns a promise.

Answer (score 4):

Because [mkdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_mode_callback) is `async`.

**Example:**

If you do:

```
fs.mkdir('test');
fs.statSync('test').isDirectory();//might return false cause it might not be created yet
```

But if you do:

```
fs.mkdir('test', function() {
    fs.statSync('test').isDirectory();//will be created at this point
});
```

You can still use [mkdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_mode) if you need a `sync` version.

Comment: There is no such method `mkdirAsync`. There is however a `mkdir` and `mkdirSync` function. It seems like most methods have those two types of functions. An asynchronous method with no suffix and a synchronous method with the `Sync` suffix. You can check it out in a node console, by requiring a module and then typing in the variable name. ie `fs`

Comment: Yes, true, made a type

Comment: You can also use `promisify` to convert it to promise so you can just await it.


`await fs.mkdir('test')`,`fs.statSync('test').isDirectory()`

Answer (score 2):

Many things could go wrong by using `mkdir`, and you should probably handle exceptions and errors and return them back to the user, when possible.

e.g. `mkdir /foo/bar` could go wrong, as you might need `root` (sudo) permissions in order to create a top-level folder.

However, the general idea behind callbacks is that the method you're using is asynchronous, and given the way Javascript works you might want to be notified and continue your program execution once the directory has been created.

Update: bare in mind that if you need — let's say — to save a file in the directory, you'll need to use that callback:

```
fs.mkdir('/tmp/test', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('failed to write directory', err);
    }

    // now, write a file in the directory
});

// at this point, the directory has not been created yet
```

I also recommend you having a look at promises, which are now being used more often than callbacks.

Comment: Nope, that method is always asynchronous. You can use `mkdirSync` if you need a sync one. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_mode

Answer (score 1):

Because it's an async call, it may be that further execution of the program depends on the outcome of the operation (dir created sucessfully). When the callback executes is the first point in time when this can be checked.

However, this operation is really fast, it may seem as it's happening instantly, but really (because it's async), the following line after `fs.mkdir(path);` will be executed without waiting for any feedback from the `fs.mkdir(path);` thus w/o any guarantee that the directory creation finished already, or if it failed.